# installation problem of flutter framework in git-bash

Tags: flutter, git-bash

I'm new to coding and recently tried to install flutter framework in git bash but there was a warning about android studio , by mistake I copied a line of  code from the internet

flutter config --android-studio-dir=/my/local/path/for/android/studio

which intern is giving a new warning saying

```
X android-studio-dir = C:/Program Files/Git/my/local/path/for/android/studio
X Android Studio not found at C:/Program Files/Git/my/local/path/for/android/studio
```

please, anyone, help me

I tried to write the same code giving the value of the location where the android studio is present but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Type `flutter config -h` for help.
It says

> To remove a setting, configure it to an empty string.

or you can set the correct value as

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir='correct/path/'
```

run `flutter doctor` when done